# Object interface in Java

Tags: java

I have  interface

```
public  interface Arithmetic {
   Object  sum(Object o);
}
```

and I need to assign a sum function in the Matrix class

```
public  class Matrix implements Arithmetic{
int[][] data;
public Matrix ...
public Object sum(Object o){
 // then I have to add two matrix
}
}
```

please tell me how can I add two matrices, when the first matrix type int [] [], while the second type Object

Answer (score 6):

Make `Arithmetic` generic:

```
public  interface Arithmetic<T> {
   T sum(T o);
}
```

then make `Matrix` implement `Arithmetic<Matrix>`:

```
@Override public Matrix sum(Matrix o){
```

then you can access the matrix properties of `o`.

---

Note that you might find the design cleaner if you move your operations into a separate class, e.g.

```
class MatrixArithmetic {
  static Matrix sum(Matrix a, Matrix b) {...}  // Element-wise addition of matrices.
  static Matrix sum(Matrix a, int constant) {...}  // Add constant to all elements
}
```

I'd say that is a better design because:

- It declutters the arithmetic implementations from the implementation of the data structure;
- It allows you to have different `sum` methods; `implements Arithmetic<Matrix>` precludes `implements Arithmetic<Integer>` (just as an example);
- It allows you to add "new" arithmetic methods that you need for specific reasons, without having to change the `Arithmetic` class, allowing for better modularization of your algorithms.